# "I've done everything I can" vs "I've done everything I can do"

Tags: phrase-usage

"I've done everything I can"

"I've done everything I can **do**"

Which of the above is the grammatically correct version? Is the "do" at the end needed?

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the structure in "as best you can"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/44194/what-is-the-structure-in-as-best-you-can)

Answer (score 4):

Both are grammatically correct.

I believe that the first is more common, but I do not find the second one at all strange.

Answer (score 3):

It is fine to elide a verb after an auxiliary verb. It's simply a matter of omitting a verb whose meaning can be ascertained from the prior clause.  Since it's understandable, it's acceptable.

This is [also discussed here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/317847/omitting-verbs-is-it-correct).

Another example would be

> He ran as far as he can

instead of

> He ran as far as he can **run**.

Or:

> Be good, if you can

instead of

> Be good, if you can **be good**.

Answer (score -1):

"I've done everything I can" is correct

;-)

Rather "I've done everything I can do" one might say "I've done all I can do"